# Are the additive identity and additive inverse of a quotient space unique?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, quotient-spaces

Suppose $U$ is a subspace of $V$. It seems that any element in $\{u+U:u\in U\}$ could be the additive identity of the quotient space $V/U$. And for any $v+U \in V/U$, any element in $\{(-v+u)+U:u\in U\}$ could be its additive inverse. Does that mean additive identity and additive inverse might not be unique?

Comment: The elements of $V/U$ are cosets. For any $u_1, u_2\in U$, the elements $u_1+U, u_2+U$ are the same coset. You can write this element in different ways (using different representatives), but it's still the same element. In general, it is easy to prove that identity and inverses are always unique.

Comment: $\{u+U:u\in U\}=\{U\}$ and $\{(-v+u)+U:u\in U\}=\{-v+U\}.$

Comment: @TedShifrin These set brackets are mandatory and *are* precise notations. Both sides are sets of cosets. What these equalities are telling is that the OP's sets (of the left hand side) are singletons.  And we have $u+U=U$ for *all* $u\in U.$

Comment: You *are* arguing further. My set equalities said the same thing as you about the cosets $u+U$ for each $u\in U.$ I do not understand your sentence about what you do not want to write. I copied-pasted the OP's sets and rewrote them more simply, to let them understand why their  "any element" in their sets were actually unique. P.s. Neither do I. May be you could ask someone else their opinion about my formulas? This would surely be more helpful.